# Godaddy's sub-domain cannot forward to name base virtual host

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I used Amazon Ec2 instance and I usually forward domain and sub-domains to create multiple website on single instance server. It working perfect with domain purchased from another domain registerer. 
Unfortunately, I purchased domain from Godaddy, create subdomain and forward to same ip address with same technology is not working. It always show the first website. Anyone can help with this issue?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin xx.xxx.x.xx
ServerName sub.domian.com
#DirectoryIndex public/index.php
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/foldername"
ErrorLog "logs/name-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/foldername-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What does an "nslookup" or "dig" command return for both your "first" website and the subdomain?

Comment: It's all coming out same result.No luck. It is working with 1&1 domain but only error with Godaddy's domain.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fixed by myself to work multiple sub-domain website on single EC2 Instance. At first, I set server ip address in Sub-Domain "Forward to" address.
But, in the A Record of sub-domain is seem like "Forwarded" and I simply change it to my server IP. Now it is working.